# Strong number identifier (Ruby code issue)

Tags: ruby

I need to write some code that can identify a Strong Number.

A strong number is the number that the sum of the factorial of its digits is equal to number itself.

For example : 145 , since 1! + 4! + 5! = 1 + 24 + 120 = 145

I've been trying to solve this but to no avail. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? I need the "adder" and "multiplier" variables to increase with each loop, so I can compare the total at the end of the method, but they keep defaulting to zero. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

```
def strong_num(n)
  digits=n.divmod(1)
  multiplier=1
  adder=0

  digits.each do |digit|
    x=digit
    digit-1.times do
      multiplier=multiplier*x
      adder=adder+multiplier

      x=x-1
    end
  end

  if n==adder
    return "STRONG!!!!"
  else 
    return "Not Strong !!"
  end
end
```

Sample input:

```
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(1)  , "STRONG!!!!")
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(2)  , "STRONG!!!!")
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(7)  , "Not Strong !!")
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(93) , "Not Strong !!")
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(145), "STRONG!!!!")
Test.assert_equals(strong_num(185), "Not Strong !!")
```

Sample output:

```
Test Passed: Value == "STRONG!!!!"
Test Passed: Value == "STRONG!!!!"
Expected: "Not Strong !!", instead got: "STRONG!!!!"
Expected: "Not Strong !!", instead got: "STRONG!!!!"
Test Passed: Value == "STRONG!!!!"
Expected: "Not Strong !!", instead got: "STRONG!!!!"
Test Passed: Value == "STRONG!!!!"
Expected: "Not Strong !!", instead got: "STRONG!!!!"
```

Comment: Can you please post some example input and the expected output?

Comment: Note: `digit-1.times do` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Also `n.divmod(1)` does NOT return number's digits.

Comment: Can you edit in the definition of a "strong" number?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!
I have tried to reduce the code by breaking it into pieces

Input: 145

```
def method_name(num)
  array = num.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i) # => [1,4,5]
  fact_arr = array.map {|f| fact(f)} # => [1, 24, 120]

  if (num == fact_arr.inject(:+))
    return "STRONG!!"
  else
    return "NOT STRONG!!"
  end
end

def fact(n)
  if (n == 0)
    1
  else
    n * fact(n-1)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient way of calculating a factorial, BTW. Even if tail call optimization was on, this function is __not__ tail-recursive.

Comment: In fact, no need to bother with recursion at all. A simple `(1..n).reduce(:*)` will suffice.

Comment: I had a thought of `number.downto(1).inject(:*)` but to keep it simple I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

`k.divmod(n)` returns an array = [quocient_of_division(k/n), rest of division(k/n)]. Example: `145.divmod(1)` returns `=>[145, 0]`. Also, `digit-1.times` in your code should be `(digit-1).times`

The way I thought that this could be done is like this:

```rb
def is_strong?(number)
  result = 0
  numbers = number.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i)
  powers = { 0 => 1, 1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 6, 4 => 24, 5 => 120, 6 => 760, 7 => 5040, 8 => 40320, 9 => 362880 }
  numbers.each do |n|
    result += powers[n]
  end  
  return (result == number)
end
```